# Server Error in '/test' Application while deploying Angular 2+ app on IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I'm trying to run an angular 2+ application on IIS. I have done everything like in https://angular.io/guide/deployment. I've copied contents of dist folder to inside a sub folder (test) of server root, set base href to /test/ and added url rewrite rule.

But when I tried to browse it, I'm getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/test' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog (DWORD) to 1. 
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Is there anyone who faced with this kind of problem?

Can it be about the confliction of web.config files between in server root for another app and angular 2+ app's?

Comment: I've used Angular CLI and Vs code as development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing ApplicationInsightsWebTracking Module in test application's modules part on IIS.